# How to detect and handle collisions in java list accessed in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I have a grid of cars, with each car having a unique position (x, y) on the grid, and who can move. I have a mediator which has a reference to the list of these cars, and which is supposed to control the cars moves on the grid, notably controlling that only one car can have the same position (x, y) at a time (avoid collisions).

In the mediator, cars can be registered (`List` add), and to avoid collisions, the list of cars must be iterated each time before a car is told to move, in order to check their current positions. Of course, we are in a multithreaded environment, in a thread-by-car model, which means one thread can potentially register a new car, while another thread can move an existing car at the same time, resulting in collision if the two cars have the same position (x, y).

To handle the list of cars, I see 2 solutions : `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and a simple `ArrayList` with ReentrantLock/Condition objects.

If I understand well, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is thread safe but provides only a copy of the list of cars which is not always the latest version of the underlying array. So, I might get collisions using it.
Otherwise, I can use a simple `ArrayList` with a ReentrantLock to lock the register and handleMove methods, and a Condition object to make the current thread wait if a potential collision is detected.

In my opinion, I should use the `ArrayList` with the lock.
Do you confirm `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not suitable in this case ? Do you have another solution ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)?

Comment: synchronized is basically doing the same thing than using lock. Ok fine. But what I want to be sure is if I can remove the CopyOnWriteArrayList from the potential solutions. I edit my question. thanks.

Comment: As far as i understood, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` gives you a thread safe **snapshot** to iterate through and won't reflect concurrent changes to the original list while you are iterating (and therefore, no chances to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`). It seems to be useful if you don't care about what is going on in the original list while you are iterating through the _snapshot_. So it does not fit your needs.
[see API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: @ricardo.scholz Exactly. So, do you think the ArrayList with lock is enough ? I don't understand evgeniy-dorofeev proposition to use Collections.synchronizedList if I have to also use a synchronized block. ArrayList + ReentrantLock is enough for me.

Comment: @rico you have to use a synchronized block when iterating, but when writing to a synchronizedList the list method itself synchronizes on the list object so you don't have to. If you use a plain ArrayList, you will have to synchronize on the list when writing too.

Comment: @rico, I woudn't know wether `ArrayList` + `ReentrantLock` would be enough, I'm not familiar with `ReentrantLock` usage. Sorry.

Comment: @rico if you are doing your own locking using `ReentrantLock` then there's no need to use `synchronizedList`; just use a plain `ArrayList` but remember to do all locking wherever you access it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Ok. Fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a synchronized list. You can make ArrayList synchronized with Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList). And make sure no thread changes the list while you are iterating it

```
   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
       ...
   synchronized (list) {
       Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
       while (i.hasNext())
           foo(i.next());
   }
```

Comment: 2 comments : 1. why is it better than using a CopyOnWriteArrayList ? 2. If you use a synchronized block for a list, why not using a simple ArrayList instead ? If I understand well, your solution is equivalent to using a CopyOnWriteArrayList with a supplementary lock for read access to be sure to have the latest version of the underlying array. That's why I consider using ArrayList with a lock is enough, because I don't need to add synchronization to synchronization.

Comment: 1. as far as I understood you dont want a thread to insert an element while your are iterating 2. synchronized block prevents changing list during iteration, but it does not synchronize add /remove operations on the list

Comment: Ok. So your proposition is : Collections.synchronizedList to sync add/remove operations on the list + synchronized block to sync iterations. My proposition in the question is : ArrayList + lock in read part to sync iterations + lock in write/remove part. It seems to be equivalent, isn't it ?

Comment: I am not sure how lock in read part will sync iterations. What I offered is the standandard solution of the problem of List synchronization, it is from Collections.synchronizedList API. You need to synchronize Iterator and List